# implementing json iteration

Tags: javascript, json

I have the below JSON and need to iterate thru the "rule" object. I can never seems to call it correctly to be able access more than just the last rule.

If someone could point me in the right direction, i'd appreciate it

```
var rules = [{
"rule":[{
    "fields":["CASE.PROSECUTED_FLAG","CASE.RESTITUTION_SIGNED"],
    "conditions":["N","Y"],
    "actions":"required",
    "action_fields":["test1","test2"]
}],
"rule":[{
    "fields":["CASE.PROSECUTED_FLAG","CASE.RESTITUTION_SIGNED"],
    "conditions":["N","N"],
    "actions": "required",
    "action_fields": ["test3", "test4"]
}],
 "rule":[{
    "fields":["CASE.PROSECUTED_FLAG"],
    "conditions":["Y"],
    "actions": "required",
    "action_fields": ["test5"]
}]
}];




function rulesControl() {
    alert(rules.length);
    for (var rule in rules) {

    var xfields = rules[rule].rule.fields;
    var conditions = rules[rule].rule.conditions;
    var actions = rules[rule].rule.actions;
    var action_fields = rules[rule].rule.action_fields;

    //test the fields (if success, mark them, else clear them)
    if (validateRule(xfields, conditions)) {
        rulesAction(actions, action_fields);
    } else {
        ruleActionMakeClear(action_fields);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can one really have several attributes with the same name ("rule") in a json object?  Use an array instead.  Hmm... maybe this was an answer...

Comment: You shall not use `for..in` to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because that JSON is oddly formed. It defines the property "rule" on teh containing object three times, in essence overwriting itself. This is probably more what you are after, rather than having all those single item arrays nested in objects.

```
var rules = [
{"rule":
    {
    "fields":["CASE.PROSECUTED_FLAG","CASE.RESTITUTION_SIGNED"],
    "conditions":["N","Y"],
    "actions":"required",
    "action_fields":["test1","test2"]
    }
},
{"rule":
    {
    "fields":["CASE.PROSECUTED_FLAG","CASE.RESTITUTION_SIGNED"],
    "conditions":["N","N"],
    "actions": "required",
    "action_fields": ["test3", "test4"]
    }
},
{"rule":
    {
    "fields":["CASE.PROSECUTED_FLAG"],
    "conditions":["Y"],
    "actions": "required",
    "action_fields": ["test5"]
    }
}
];
```

You would access this as:

```
rules[i].rule.PROPERTY
```

Where i is the index value for the rule and PROPERTY is fields, conditions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing curlies...

```
var rules = [{"rule":[{}]
      },{  // You are missing this curly braces.
      "rule":[{}]},
      {"rule":[{}]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `rule` key the reason why you see the last rule only is because the rules overwrite each other and the last one is what remains, I suggest using an array to store the rules.